# Wicket Re-directions - Not able to share link facebook

Tags: redirect, wicket

I have a weired problem wherein a redirection is happening and I am not able to post it on a Facebook link for slug based URL. Regular URL are working fine.

The slug based user friendly URL is :

example.com/webapp/poll/who-is-the-most-important-person-in-the-country-in-2014-T196

It causes a redirection to happen -

example.com/mysite-webapp/wicket/page?1

internally.
When I post it on facebook it shows "Page Not Found"
But if you click it it works.

My question is why Wicket is redirecting it to "example.com/mysite-webapp/wicket/page?1". It doesn't happen for non-slug based URL.

In Wicket Application I have defined it as -
mount(new MountedMapperWithoutPageComponentInfo("poll/${pollName}-T${pollId}", PollDetailsPage.class));